# a way to automatically split a video into chapters?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, machine-learning-model, topic-model

Given a video with audio, we can use ASR to get a script of the sentences and timestamps. We are looking for a way to group the sentences into chapters. There are several companies that are doing it nicely - [Google on YouTube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9884579?hl=en), [Assembly AI](https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/introducing-assemblyai-auto-chapters-summarize-audio-and-video-files/), but we couldn't find any good resource or paper that explains the research behind how they do it. BertTopic seems to give us just a topic for each sentence, but not a way to split the video. it also doesnt account for timestamps.

Wondered if anyone has any links or any other ideas?

Thanks very much!

Lior